# Retrieve items limited by a field's value inside of a list of objects

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I apologise if the title is confusing, but I had a hard time coming up with a good title. :(

I have indexed several news articles that looks like this (shortened):

```
{
    title: "This is definitely a sports article",
    categories: [
        {
            name: "General",
            isMain: false,
        },
        {
            name: "Sports",
            isMain: true,
        }
    ]
},
{
    title: "Slightly sportsrelated, but mostly politics",
    categories: [
        {
            name: "Politics",
            isMain: true,
        },
        {
            name: "Sports",
            isMain: false,
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem is that I have to retrieve a list of articles belonging to the "Sports" category, but limited to articles where the "Sports" category's field "isMain" is set to true.

Is that even possible?

(Using Elasticsearch 5.6.6, and I'm unable to reindex and add a "mainCategory" field, unfortunately.)

Comment: Yes, its possible. We are using this in production - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Comment: The problem is that the "categories" field isn't of the nested type, it's just a list of plain objects; I have no control over the mapping and/or the indexing process, unfortunately.